# Cannot serialize an Enum to GWT

Tags: gwt, serialization, enums

I am unable to serialize an Enum to GWT if it implements java.io.Serializable. It will GWT compile successfully, but at runtime, I get the dreaded:

> Type 'com....security..AdminPrivilege' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer.For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = Login to  Console

If I implement com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable it compiles and runs fine. I am trying to avoid IsSerializable, since this Enum is persisted in our DB and is referenced in non-GWT servlets. I do not want to introduce a GWT dependancy, even for that single class.

I've read most of the discussions on this topic here. I have:

1. added a serialVersionUid (which should not be necessary)
2. added a no-arg constructor (but this is an Enum, so it must be private - I suspect this may be the problem)
3. added a callable RPC method that returns the Enum and takes a Set of the Enum as an input argument (trying to get this Enum into the whitelist) -

For all other Enums, I generated a GWT version which implements IsSerializable. But this new Enum is too complex to generate and I need the methods from the Enum in the GWT code.

Thanks for any help on this.

My Enum is below. Notice it has an embedded Enum:

```
public enum AdminPrivilege implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Privileges
    MANAGE_XX("Manage XX", PrivilegeCategory.XX), 
    IMPORT_LICENSE("Import a License", PrivilegeCategory.XX), 
    SUBMIT_BUG("Submit a Bug", PrivilegeCategory.XX), 
    TEST_AD("Test AD", PrivilegeCategory.XX),

    // Administrator Privileges
    LOGIN("Login to XX", PrivilegeCategory.ADMIN), 
    MANAGE_ADMIN("Manage Administrators", PrivilegeCategory.ADMIN), 
    MANAGE_ROLE("Manage Roles", PrivilegeCategory.ADMIN),

    // Task Privileges
    CANCEL_TASK("Cancel Tasks", PrivilegeCategory.TASK), ;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Defines the privilege categories.
     * 
     */
    public enum PrivilegeCategory implements java.io.Serializable {

        XX("XX"), 
        ADMIN("Administrator"), 
        TASK("Task"), ;

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

        private String displayValue;

        // This constructor is required for GWT serialization
        private PrivilegeCategory() {
        }

        private PrivilegeCategory(String displayValue) {
            this.displayValue = displayValue;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return displayValue;
        }
    }

    private String displayValue;
    private AdminPrivilege parentPrivilege;
    private PrivilegeCategory privilegeCategory;

    // This constructor is required for GWT serialization
    private AdminPrivilege() {
    }

    private AdminPrivilege(String displayValue, PrivilegeCategory category) {
        this.displayValue = displayValue;
        this.privilegeCategory = category;
    }

    private AdminPrivilege(String displayValue, PrivilegeCategory category, AdminPrivilege parent) {
        this(displayValue, category);
        this.parentPrivilege = parent;
    }

    /**
     * Return the parent privilege for this privilege.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public AdminPrivilege getParentPrivilege() {
        return parentPrivilege;
    }

    /**
     * Return the category for this privilege.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public PrivilegeCategory getPrivilegeCategory() {
        return privilegeCategory;
    }

    /**
     * Return the set of categories.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static Set<PrivilegeCategory> getPrivilegeCategories() {
        Set<PrivilegeCategory> category = new HashSet<PrivilegeCategory>();
        for (PrivilegeCategory c : PrivilegeCategory.values()) {
            category.add(c);
        }
        return category;
    }

    /**
     * Return the set of privileges for a category.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static Set<AdminPrivilege> getPrivileges(PrivilegeCategory category) {
        Set<AdminPrivilege> privileges = new HashSet<AdminPrivilege>();
        for (AdminPrivilege p : AdminPrivilege.values()) {
            if (category.equals(p.getPrivilegeCategory())) {
                privileges.add(p);
            }
        }
        return privileges;
    }

    /**
     * Return the set of child privileges for a specific privilege
     * 
     * @param parent
     * @return
     */
    public static Set<AdminPrivilege> getChildPrivileges(AdminPrivilege parent) {
        Set<AdminPrivilege> children = new HashSet<AdminPrivilege>();
        for (AdminPrivilege priv : values()) {
            if (parent.equals(priv.getParentPrivilege())) {
                children.add(priv);
            }
        }
        return children;
    }

    /**
     * Return the set of privileges that are parent privileges
     * 
     * @return
     */
        public static Set<AdminPrivilege> getParentPrivileges() {
            Set<AdminPrivilege> parents = new HashSet<AdminPrivilege>();
            for (AdminPrivilege priv : values()) {
                if (priv.getParentPrivilege() == null) {
                    parents.add(priv);
                }
            }
            return parents;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That's really strange. A simple enum should be serializable by default with no changes. Post your enum code.

Comment: Well - it's not a simple Enum - it's got an embedded Enum. Here it is:

Comment: this exact enum works fine for me under gwt 2.3.0 - more code context?

Comment: @MarioP - Sorry, I added the version using IsSerializable (which works for me too). I'm trying to get it to work using java.io.Serializable. I've modified my post to correct that.

Comment: @PeterD - my comment remains the same. works fine in gwt 2.3.0 - context?

Comment: @MarioP - There are significantly more enums defined (~40), but that shouldn't change anything. I am trying to serialize a java.util.Set of them inside an Administrator object, which also has a name and description String property. I added a dummy service method to attempt to get this into GWT's whitelist. This dummy method returned the Enum and took an Enum as an input arg. I never tried calling this to see if I could serialize it alone.

Comment: @PeterD - i can't reproduce this error, no matter what i do. can you provide a code snipped where you try to serialize an administrator object?

Comment: @MarioP - I use the following code to create the proxy object (AdminRoleGWT) that represents the AdminRole object that contains the Set of AdminPrivileges:                                        `public static AdminRoleGWT summarize(AdminRole role)
    {
        AdminRoleGWT roleGWT = new AdminRoleGWT(
                role.getDescription(),
                role.getAllowPrivileges(),
                AdminRoleTypeGWT.valueOfDisplayValue(role.getType().toString()),
                role.getName(),
                role.getId()
                );
        return roleGWT;
    }`

Comment: @PeterD - strange. and what do you do with this AdminRoleGWT?

Comment: I return it from my ServiceImpl class:`    @Override
    public AdminRoleGWT getAdminRole(java.lang.Long id, java.lang.String tx)
    {
        AdminRole adminRole = adminManager.getAdminRole(id, tx);
        return (AdminRoleGWT)GWTFactory.summarizeObject(adminRole);
    }
`

Comment: Enums do not follow the same serialization rules as classes  in GWT, because they are not classes. You don't need no-args constructors or implementing Serializable or IsSerializable. Enums are serialized by their code values. Your enum is fine. Post code of AdminRoleGWT class please. And any classes that AdminRoleGWT uses.

Comment: AdminRoleGWT is one of the many proxy classes that we generate for serializing to GWT. It's a simple POJO with getters and setters with the following properties:  String description, Set<AdminPrivilege> allowPrivileges, AdminRoleTypeGWT type;    <br/>AdminRoletType is a generated Enum - a simpler one that we generate.

Comment: still isn't reproducable for me - which gwt version are you using?

Comment: I got a similar error with a static inner class. I didn't isolate the problem, so I'm not posting an answer, but putting the nested class outside of the outer class solved it. It used to work earlier, but I kept adding fields and broke at some point; not sure what the cause might be.

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified a parameterized constructor in your enum?  If you have, and it has parameters, you need to remember to add a no-parameters constructor as well, even if you don't use it, because GWT will need it.  Adding a parameterized constructor and forgetting to add a parameterless one gets me every time, at least with non-enum classes.

Comment: Yes - that's what I mean by no-arg constructor. As I said, since this is an Enum that constructor has to be private so I suspect that may be the root cause of this problem, since GWT claims that this works.